# Suse 12.5 | error after "chage" cmd when changing password

Tags: linux, password, opensuse

When i try to change my password after this commande "chage -d 0 root"

I have those 2 message :

> Password has been already used. Choose another.
>
> Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service.

But the password's still changed (and i never used this password before)

Do you know where this error come from ? (it's for a client)

Answer (score 0):

I found, in /etc/pam.d/common-password

have to put the line with "unix.so" at the bottom of the file